# pairs of similar code produces different results caused by "except" statements

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to sort data in the form list1=[a,b,c] list2=[d,e,f] into the form [[a,d],[b,e],[c,f]]. If only [a,b,c] [d] or [a] [d,e,f] is given, I want it to result in [[a,d],[b,d],[c,d]] or [[a,d],[a,e],[a,f]], respectively. It seems to be handling list2 correctly, but not list1.

I've added print statements to see what it's doing. I've also given the both pairs of code the same lists (not in shared code), but it handles them differently.

```
def synthesize(file_name,number_of_notes,root_note,duration,fuctions,frequency_ratios=[1]):
    note_data=[]
    for n in range(number_of_notes):
        note_data.append(["",""])
        try:
            note_data[n][0]=fuctions[n]
            print(functions[n])
            print("true")
        except:
            note_data[n][0]=fuctions[0]
            print(fuctions[0])
            print("false")
        print("\n")
        try:
            note_data[n][1]=str(frequency_ratios[n])
            print(frequency_ratios[n])
            print("true")
        except:
            note_data[n][1]=str(frequency_ratios[0])
            print(frequency_ratios[0])
            print("false")
        print("\n")
        print(note_data)
        print("\n")
```

Output:

```
 >>> synthesize("test.wav",3,"C#",1,["sin(x)","sin(x+1)","sin(x+2)"],[4,5,6])
sin(x)
false


4
true


[['sin(x)', '4']]


sin(x)
false


5
true


[['sin(x)', '4'], ['sin(x)', '5']]


sin(x)
false


6
true


[['sin(x)', '4'], ['sin(x)', '5'], ['sin(x)', '6']]
```

I expected there to be no "false" prints.

Comment: This is the danger of using bare `except:` clauses: you may catch errors other than the one you intended.  Specifically, you spelled `functions` right in only one place (in a `print()`), resulting in a `NameError`.  If you caught only the `IndexError` that results when one of the input lists is short, you would have seen this.

Comment: Now, that's a bruh moment. Thanks for the help!